# Can I use libtool output in cgo?

Tags: go, static-libraries, dependency-management, libtool

I am call static library which is compiled from c++ source. But It is tiring to write dependency libs and I find that libtool just do very well, for example, my `libfoo.la` will have something like this:

```
dependency_libs=‘ /Users/roger/example/lib/bar/libbar.la -lm’
```

Now I am calling `libfoo.a` in golang, but the dependencies can be complicated. `libfoo.a`depends on `libbar.a` ,`libbar.a` depends on `libhaha.a`. **can I make use of `libfoo.la` when I build golang?**(or some way make `libfoo.a` and all its dependencies into one lib file?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I make use of libfoo.la when I build golang?

No.  Go has it's own build system that doesn't know about libtool archives, only the standard static/shared libraries available on the system.

> Now I am calling libfoo.a in golang, but the dependencies can be complicated.

That's how it is with static libs.  Which is one reason for using shared libs instead.  Shared libs are also not trouble-free in Go, but are somewhat manageable.

> libfoo.a depends on libbar.a ,libbar.a depends on libhaha.a.

Doesn't something like:

```
package foo


// #cgo CFLAGS: -I...
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L... -lfoo -lbar -lhaha -lm
// #include ...
import "C"
...
```

work?

> or some way make libfoo.a and all its dependencies into one lib file?

Yes, that's possible but another question.